# Insert the lowest possible unique positve integer in an atomic fashion in MySql

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table with a unique positive integer field. I currently have rows with id's of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 35]. Is there a insert query that I could write that would assign the id field to the lowest unique positive integer (in this case 6)? It would have to do this atomically so there isn't the possibility of concurrent inserts wiping out each other or failing.

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this? You're not thinking of reusing IDs of deleted items are you?

Comment: This is a simplified case, but it is analogous to 20 being someone's favorite number so they want to use that as their id. I would like to use 1-19 instead of auto-incrementing to 21 next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **not** use this to fill up "missing" ids, but this should work:

```
Insert Into t (id)
  Select Coalesce( Min(t.id) + 1, 0 )
  From t
  Left Join t As t2 On ( t2.id = t.id + 1 )
  Where t2.id Is Null
```

Get all `id`s where `id + 1` does not exist (`Left Join`), and insert `Min(id)+1` or `0` if non is available.