# Finding the first integer not used in a collection of integers

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

After retrieving a list of integers used for ID in a mysql database, taking in that all the ID doesn't follow each other in each case (for example list could be [1,2,3,5,10,11,12,20,...]), what would be an more efficient way, aside from looping through all the integers, to find the lowest integer which isn't yet in the list (in our case, it would be 4, then 6 once 4 is attributed). Also it shouldn't be higher than 999.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640335/insert-the-lowest-possible-unique-positve-integer-in-an-atomic-fashion-in-mysql) give a mysql query, but I would like to do it in my php script, except if it would be more efficient.

Comment: Why do you need to find these numbers?

Comment: @sapht: It is so that I have db entries that are uniquely defined by an ID and a category, meaning that an ID can be used twice, but not in the same category. I am on a project with a lot of history, and it went so that ID at one point wasn't given on a consecutive manner, but manually. Now the tool needs to generate the ID itself, what I normally do is take the higher ID and add one. But we have the problem of the limit set to the ID, which can't be higher than 999.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be solved easily and efficiently using a **binary search** (which runs in O(log n), faster than a linear search, which is O(n)).  The basic idea is that if and only if all the numbers are present up to a certain index, then list[index] = index + 1 (e.g. list[0] = 1, list[1] = 2, etc).  This property can be used to determine whether the smallest missing number is before or after a certain element of the list, allowing for a binary search.

The implementation is simple (I don't know php, so here's pseudocode)

```
lower_bound = 0
upper_bound = length(list) - 1
index = floor((lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2)
while (lower_bound != upper_bound)  
     if(list[index] = index + 1)     // missing number is after index
          lower_bound = index + 1
          index = floor((lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2)
     else                            // missing number is at or before index
          upper_bound = index
          index = floor((lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2)
missing_number = upper_bound + 1     // add 1 because upper_bound is the index
```

And `missing_number` will be the smallest missing number, or if there are no missing numbers it will be `length(list) + 1`.

---

Or using recursion, which I hear is less efficient

```
first_missing_number(list, lower_bound, upper_bound) {
     if(lower_bound = upper_bound)  // found the first missing number
          return upper_bound + 1    // add 1 because upper_bound is the index
     index = floor((lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2)
     if (list[index] = index + 1)   // missing number is after index
          first_missing_number(list, index + 1, upper_bound)
     else                           // missing number is at or before index
          first_missing_number(list, lower_bound, index)
}
```

In which case `first_missing_number(list, 0, length(list) - 1)` will return the first number missing from the list.  If there are no numbers missing, it returns `length(list) + 1`.

I hope this helps!

upd: php version

```
function first_free($list) {
    $lwr = 0;
    $upr = count($list);

    while ($lwr < $upr) { 
        $m = ($lwr + $upr) >> 1;
        if($list[$m] == $m + 1)
            $lwr = $m + 1;
        else
            $upr = $m;
    }
    return $upr + 1;
}
```

Comment: Damn that was simple, the last time I had this problem, I ended up using a hash table + indexed tree. Now I feel like a doof. Nice solution!

Answer (score 3):

the most efficient way is the simple loop:

```
foreach($list as $n => $v)
   if($v !== $n + 1) return $n + 1;
```

Comment: This will get very inefficient over time depending on server load, etc.  Of course, it would be much worse if he had to iterate over tens of thousands (or more) of keys, but this is best handled by the native code in MySQL than being interpreted via PHP each time the script is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_diff()` function:

eg:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "1", "2", "3", "4");
$array2 = array("b" => "2", "4");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

this will give you the missing items in the second array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be more efficient way:

```
$your_list = array(....);
$number_you_want = min(array_diff(range(1,999), $your_list));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are limited to only 999 possible keys, I'd probably create a temporary table with all possible keys (i.e. 1-999), or even create a permanent table just for this purpose, then you can do sql like this:

```
SELECT key_value FROM temp_key_table WHERE key_value NOT IN (SELECT key FROM original_table ORDER BY key ASC) ORDER BY key_value ASC LIMIT 1
```

Not sure how practical this is, and a SQL guru could probably give you a better solution, but this should work in a pinch, rather than messing with this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array   = array(1,2,3,5,10,11,12,20);
$missing = array_diff(range(min($array), max($array)), $array);

// First missing number is at $missing[0], next at $missing[1], etc.
```

Comment: @discipulus, you're mistaken. It will work fine if `1` is missing or otherwise.

Comment: but since the start value given to range is min($array), if 1 is missing from $array then the array returned by range will not include 1 either.  Thus the array_diff will not include 1 either, which in fact is the smallest missing number.  (I should add that my understanding of the question was to find the smallest integer in [1 .. 999] that was missing).